# Is $f(x)=\sin(x)$ the unique real function that satisfies $f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1, f''(0) = 0, f'''(0) = -1 ...$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Proposition:

Let $f(x)$ be a real function such that:

$$f^{(4n+k)}(0)=
   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & k = 1 \\
      1 & k = 2 \\
      0 & k = 3 \\
      -1 & k = 4 \\
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$
Then, $f(x) = \sin(x)$.

It seems like the Maclaurin series definition of $\sin(x)$ might be useful, but I am not sure if it can be used to prove uniqueness.

Comment: You can't get uniqueness (it might seem bothersome, but a lot of advanced tools wouldn't work if you could show uniqueness, so it's actually a good thing)

Comment: If $f$ is any function which agrees with $\sin$ near $0$, then it will have the desired property. For instance, if $f(x)=\sin x$ for $x\in (-0.1,0.1)$, and $f(x)=1$ otherwise, then $f$ has the same derivatives as $\sin$ at $0$, but $f$ is not equal to $\sin$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a matter of fact the function $e^{-1/x^2}$ has all its derivatives with value $0$ in $x=0$, therefore it is not equal to its Taylor series.

As a consequence for any $g$ relatively "quiet" then so will be $g(x)e^{-1/x^2}$, and you can throw away the unicity of $\sin(x)$ since you can add a function to it that has all its derivatives $0$ in $x=0$.

Now if you assume that $f(x)$ is entire (has a Taylor Series development) then you can use the series to find an ODE verified by $f$ and use maximality theorems related to linear ODE with constant coefficients

e.g. see [Determining a function by its Taylor series coeficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3437362/399263)

Answer (score 1):

Take any function that is equal to sin(x) for -eps < x < eps and has arbitrary other values elsewhere.